# Error: this template attempted to load component assembly 'Microsoft.DriverKit.DriverWizard'

Tags: visual-studio-2013, wdm

I am getting the following error when I try to create an empty project in Visual Studio 2013 for WDM

> Error: this template attempted to load component assembly
>   'Microsoft.DriverKit.DriverWizard, Version=6.4.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. For more information on this problem
>   and how to enable this template, please see documentation on
>   Customizing Project Templates.

[image]

**Procedure to get this error:**

```
New Project > Templates > Visual C++ > Windows Driver > WDM > Empty WDM Driver
```

Request help in resolving this problem as I am not able to understand the reason for the problem or the means to resolve it. Any help will be appreciated.